# How to store some grouped values in an array, vector or matrix structure in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

My problem is about storing some changeble number of value groups as one dimensional in an array, a vector or a matrix in matlab.

If we think the values are like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6....
```

I want to keep them dynamically in a structure as each group is one element of this structure, for example:

```
    a = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
    b = [2 2 2 2 2]
    c = [3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
    d = [4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
    e = [5 5 5]
    f = [6 6 6 6 6]

    x = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to use cell arrays for this. But you can do this more compactly using [run-length coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a structure:

```
>> myStruct.a = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
>> myStruct.b = [2 2 2 2 2];
>> myStruct.c = [3 3 3 3 3 3 3];
>> myStruct.d = [4 4 4 4 4 4 4];
>> myStruct.e = [5 5 5];
>> myStruct.f = [6 6 6 6 6]
myStruct = 
    a: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
    b: [2 2 2 2 2]
    c: [3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
    d: [4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
    e: [5 5 5]
    f: [6 6 6 6 6]
```

Or, if you want to numerically index your object, use a cell array:

```
>> myCell{1} = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
>> myCell{2} = [2 2 2 2 2];
>> myCell{3} = [3 3 3 3 3 3 3];
>> myCell{4} = [4 4 4 4 4 4 4];
>> myCell{5} = [5 5 5];
>> myCell{6} = [6 6 6 6 6];
>> myCell{:}
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
ans =
     2     2     2     2     2
ans =
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
ans =
     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
ans =
     5     5     5
ans =
     6     6     6     6     6
```

Comment: cell array is better.

Comment: @Shai: "better" is the enemy of "good" :) Anyway, I thought a structure is what the OP is after, since his example sort of hints in that direction. But it really depends on his specific application which one is better.

Comment: Cell array was helpful. Thanks for all of your responses.